# Create a counter for actionlistener events

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have a JButton in my program, defined as follows (more or less)

```
public class MyTester{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int counter = 0;    

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                startButton.doSomething()
                counter++;
             }
           }
         );
    }
}
```

I want to be able to count the number of times that the button is clicked. Problem is, I can't declare a counter and then increment it after the call to .doSomething(), because the variable has to be final for me to reference it in the inner class.

Is there a way to do this, other than creating my own wrapper class with its own .increment() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on threading situation, you can move the variable to the enclosing class. But this can go very wrong if you invoke `foo()` several times, since that will use the same counter.

```
public class MyClass {

    // Notice the placement outside the main()    
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                startButton.doSomething()
                //do some more stuff

                counter++;

             }
           }
         );    
    }
}
```

Comment: Just clarified the question - that is basically what I want to do, but I still run into the same situation of trying to mutate a final variable.

Comment: There's a difference between my and your code. My `counter` is not inside the main() function, but rather in the enclosing class. I'll update my example.

Answer (score 2):

You can move your counter from outside the `ActionListener` to inside, making it a member of the listener.

```
public class MyTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {           
            int counter; // you make one per listener
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startButton.doSomething();
                counter++;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 A nested class that implements `ActionListener` is another alternative. Revised code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @akf, the counter can be a member of a nested class, from which members of the enclosing instance are visible. This example implements `ActionListener` to extend `AbstractAction`.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290117 */
public class ClickCount extends JPanel {

    private JButton button = new JButton(new ClickHandler("Click"));
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("0");

    public ClickCount() {
        this.add(button);
        this.add(label);
    }

    private class ClickHandler extends AbstractAction {

        int counter;

        public ClickHandler(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(String.valueOf(++counter));
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ClickCount");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ClickCount().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```