# Updating JLabel with value

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Each time the user presses a button a counter `amountWrongGuessed` gets incremented by 1. (works correctly with testing with `System.prinln`)

But how exactly do i get this to update in my label each time i press the button?

I have made a property that returns this value.

```
 public int getAmountGuessed(){
    return amountGuessed;
}
```

Next i try to get the value of the label, but the value always remains at 0.

```
lblAmountGuessDisplay = new JLabel(String.valueOf(hg.getAmountGuessed()));


private void UpdateComponents()
{
      lblAmountGuessDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(hg.getAmountGuessed()));
}/*updateComponents*/
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code, there is nothing with what you've posted so far as long as the JLabel is only being created once and UpdateComponents() is being called after the button click event.

Answer (score 1):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290277) shows one way to update a label each time a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a threading issue. Please take a look [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090615175506AALayf6).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Fredrick -- that you've not posted enough information for your question to be answerable and that it may be a reference issue -- that the JLabel you are changing is not the one that is displayed in the program. If you post more code, we'll have a better chance of giving your a decent answer.  Also, this doesn't smell like a threading issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `ActionListener` to your button.  When the `ActionListener` is notified that the button is pressed, you can increment the counter and update the `JLabel`.  The `actionPerformed` method will be triggered in the EDT, so you should be ok with threading.

```
lblAmountGuessDisplay.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            hg.incrementAmountGuessed();
            lblAmountGuessDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(hg.getAmountGuessed()));
       }
}
```

You will probably need to implement the `incrementAmountGuessed` method (which may be the root of your problem in the first place).