# How does one know what are the valid commands in Swing's getActionCommand()?

Tags: java, swing

How to know which commands are available? I tried looking up in the Java SDK, but didn't find a thing about it.

The only way I can think of is this way

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  ButtonListener() {
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
  }
}
```

but I guess those values must be hardcoded in some part of the framework. Where can I find them?

Thanks

### EDIT

Take as example the following code taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingButtonDemo.htm):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("disable".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        ...
    }

    ...
 }
```

The site's author knew there was an action command that was "disable". Where did he get that information from?

Comment: in my opinion using actioncommands just leads to fragile code. Have on listener per common functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be thinking of the [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) interface, named instances of which are used to establish default [key bindings](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) in various L&Fs. The article [*Key Bindings*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) includes a convenient utility to examine them.

Addendum: As a concrete example, the `JButton` in [`ClickCount`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290277) takes its name and action command from the nested `ClickHandler` because the `hideActionText` property of [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) is `false` by default. As another example, [*Key Bindings*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) shows that buttons have a named action for "pressed" and "released" that is created by `createButtonListener()` in [`BasicButtonUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonUI.html). [`BasicButtonListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonListener.html) in turn uses a nested [`UIAction`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/UIAction.html) to handle the two commands, as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonListener.java.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It's whatever you set.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29

My guess is the default is the name of the button.

**Your edit:**

It could have come from two places.

1. It was the **name of the button** (`new JButton("disable")`), which by default is the action command.
2. It was the command given by `setActionCommand("disable")`

It is very important to illustrate that **by design it doesn't matter what the source was**. We don't care if it's a button, drop down, menu, or anything. All that matters is the "disable" command was given. It's the command pattern. :-)

Comment: But I want to know which ones are the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

You do it by using [`setActionCommand()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29)

```
JButton jb = new JButton("MyButton");
jb.setActionCommand("MyButtonCommand");
```

EDIT:

The site's author got "disable" from  this line of code

```
b1.setActionCommand("disable");
```

Comment: From your answers, it seems maybe I am not asking what I really want to know. I current have a button and I'd like to know when it was pressed (that means, it could either be by keyboard or mouse). Is there a way to do it without having to subscribe to mouse's and keyboard's listeners?

Comment: The ActionListener exactly does that. You have to add your logic as to what you want to do when the button is pressed in `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: The question is in how to know which kind of event got raised. I know it was an Action, but there seem to be different kinds of actions, being the only way to distinguish them the getCommandAction() value. Am I right?

Comment: @devoured elysium It is generally considered better to attach one `ActionListener` per button or other control.  Then the action command is irrelevant.  Many examples do it 'the other way' & implement a single AL with an huge 'if/else' construct to decide between possible actions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no 'valid' commands. The command is intended for use by your application and has no effect on how the button is handled by Swing.

In the second code example you posted it is being setin the code at the following line

```
b1.setActionCommand("disable");
```

For buttons the default is to use the text of the button, if the action command is not set